how to manage `_id` field mongodb c# driver
So I am in a bit of pickle
Suppose I have this Class which I use to save/retrieve records from MongoDb
public class Purchase
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public PurchaseDetails Purchase { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    ...
}

So while saving if we don't provide the Id then the Id is generated to be 000000000000000000000000 and that creates conflict in the db since that _id exists
If I omit the Id field from the Purchase class then it fails while reading records from the db because there is no field to deserialize the _id into.
I am not sure what I am missing here? How can I when constructing object not provide the Id and let the driver generate random value?
Solutions I have tried

When creating the new Purchase(...) I provide the Id but in some cases we need to do ReplaceOneAsync(..., {IsUpsert = true}) and there it fails because if the object exists and id is now changed while replacing.


you should clarify what your question and provide repro. if we don't provide the Id then the Id is generated to be 000000000000000000000000 - this is unlikely, you should not provide Id when saving, it's autogenerated as _id  and mapped to Id automatically. hat creates conflict in the db since that _id exists - based on the above, this one is also unclear

My 2 cents, if you do not provide the Id, that means that you want to do the INSERT operation. Why not in your code, you detect whether the Id is default ObjectId, if true perform InsertOne, else ReplaceOne.

Otherwise, you need to set the new ObjectId your own: ObjectId.GenerateNewId() when id is not provided.

Possible duplicate: Upserting in Mongo DB and the Id problem.
